# Not able to access Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a new account on portal.azure.com. When going to Azure Active Directory tab in account I am getting this error- Access denied You do not have access Looks like you don't have access to this content. To get access, please contact the owner.[accessdenied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcecH.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have Global/Company Administrator set on your user in order to be able to view certain parts of Azure AAD. Your account administrator will be able to change the permission. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#available-roles) for more information about roles in AAD